# How can I create bitbucket repos with oAuth token?

Tags: git, curl, oauth, bitbucket

I'm trying to create a bunch of bitbucket repositories with curl and the oAuth token I received from bitbucket. My call to create a repository looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -v  -H "Authorization: Bearer 9gcHrIKxN(...)efRXD0-_9T-2qgGNtw"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  \
  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/FooBarQWD/test_create \
  -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks" }'
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-resource-423626331.html#repositoryResource-POSTanewrepository

The Header is explained here: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/concepts/oauth2.html

I can contact the server, but get the response

```
{"error": {"message": "Access token expired. Use your refresh token to obtain a new access token."}}
```

This sounds like a sensible error message, but I get the same message if I pass a wrong token-string.

If I remove the Header entry for the token and replace it with a `-u user:password` I can create a new repository so the rest of the command should be fine.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. When I copied the token out of the URL I received, I omitted a trailing "%3D%3D" which should be a "==" at the end of the token. If I append the '==', the token is accepted and the repository created.

So it seems that there is a wrong error message returned.

Comment: Yeah, looks like we could improve that error message there. Thanks for reporting back!